# How to get the rest of arguments in windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know I can get first argument with %0, second with %1, and so on.. And I can also get all arguments with %*.

Can I get all arguments from the second arguments? For example, if I run

```
foo.bat bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4
```

How can I get only `bar2 bar3 bar4`?

Answer (score 12):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET allargs=%*
IF NOT DEFINED allargs echo no args provided&GOTO :EOF 
SET arg1=%1
CALL SET someargs=%%allargs:*%1=%%
ECHO allargs  %allargs%
ECHO arg1     %arg1%
ECHO someargs %someargs%
```

This will leave `SOMEARGS` with at least one leading separator (if it is set)

Comment: Nice but did you mean `echo` (in fourth line)?

Comment: @user2033427 yeah - fixed.

Answer (score 4):

With `SHIFT` command. But with every shift you'll lose the first.
This will not change the `%*` but you'll be able to get all argument ,but the first:

```
@echo off
shift

set "arg_line= "
:parse_args
if "%~1" NEQ "" (
 arg_line=%argline% "%~1"
 goto :parse_args
)
```

now you'll have all arguments but the first stored in `%arg_line%`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SHIFT`. It moves the apparent position of the parameters, then `%*` will get all parameters from the position shifted to. You should get the first parameters before using `SHIFT`.

[More information](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) on `SHIFT`.

Comment: It's wrong,`SHIFT` only affects `%0,%1,%2 ... %9` but not `%*`

Comment: Right, I just checked, and SHIFT does not do a thing to %* but %* will give you the arguments after the first one anyway.